# Degree of a map $f: S^1 \to S^1$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, definition, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

I’m reading the following definition.

> **Definition B11.1.** Given a map $f: S^1 \rightarrow S^1$, we define its degree $\operatorname{deg} f \in \mathbb{Z}$ as follows. Choosing a basepoint $x_{0} \in \mathbb{S}^{1},$ we get
> $$
> f_{*}: \mathbb{Z} \cong \pi_{1}(\mathbb{S}^{1}, x_{0}) \mapsto \pi_{1}(\mathbb{S}^{1}, f(x_{0})) \cong \mathbb{Z}
> $$
> Any such homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ is given as multiplication by some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, meaning the map $k \mapsto n k$. We then set $\operatorname{deg} f:=n$

While in our class we’ve covered why $\mathbb{Z} \cong \pi_{1}(\mathbb{S}^{1}, x_{0})$, I’m not sure I get how that translates into equivalency between the maps $\pi_{1}(\mathbb{S}^{1}, x_{0}) \to \pi_{1}(\mathbb{S}^{1}, f(x_{0}))$ and the maps $S^1 \to S^1$. Say we embed $S^1$ into $\mathbb{R}^2$, and $f$ rotates $x_0 = (1,0)$ by an angle of $\pi/3$ around the origin. What would $n$ be in this case? And given $k \mapsto nk$, what does it mean in terms of the homotopy classes of loops in $S^1$? If it helps please use concrete numbers for $n$ and $k$.

**Edit:** It’s been pointed out to me that orientation matters. Indeed this comes right after the definition in my materials. For now, I’m just assuming we map the loop going counter-clockwise around $S^1$ once to $1$.

Comment: $n$ will be 1 in your case: the generator is mapped to the generator.
And $k \mapsto nk$ corresponds to the map that looks like $n$ in $\pi_1(S^1),$ the one where the circle winds $n$ times on itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems as though the degree is well-defined only up to a sign. The reason I say this is because while it is true that $\pi_1(\Bbb S^1, f(x_0)) \cong \Bbb Z$, there are two isomorphisms, depending on which generator you pick.

In your example, you technically haven't given a map $f: \Bbb S^1 \to \Bbb S^1$, you've only told what $f$ does to $(1, 0)$. I assume that you mean that $f$ rotates $\Bbb S^1$ by $\pi/3$. In this case, the degree could either be $+1$ or $-1$.

To get a geometric interpretation: Recall what the isomorphism $G = \pi_1(\Bbb S^1, x_0) \cong \Bbb Z$ explicitly is. There are exactly two generators of $G$. One is (the equivalence class of) the loop that goes around exactly once and the other is the reverse of that. We get the isomorphism by mapping one of them to $1$. This means that the degree of the map is simply measuring how many times the generating loop gets twisted, under $f$. The only problem is that you have a choice in fixing the isomorphism, which means that the orientation matters.

Comment: The discussion about orientation indeed comes right next to this definition. Say we map the loop going counter-clockwise around $S^1$ once to $1$. If I want a different $n$, I’d have to choose an angle greater than $2\pi$? Also any angle in $[0,2\pi)$ would give me the same degree?

Comment: Note that you'd have to fix the orientation for the domain and codomain, for it to be well-defined. Suppose that we have done that. To get a different $n$, what you have said will not suffice. No matter how you rotate, you'll always get the degree as $1$. (Even if the rotation is in the other direction.) To get a degree $n$ map, consider $\Bbb S^1 \subset \Bbb C$ and the map $z \mapsto z^n$.

Comment: For $z \mapsto z^n$, to verify that its degree is $n$, I suppose that I’d have to show that the generator loop is mapped to a loop winding around $n$ times (in the same direction as the former loop)? Also, could you elaborate why the map $e^{i\theta} \mapsto e^{i(\theta + \pi /3)}$ wouldn’t work?

Comment: @JoshNg, what you suppose is correct. The reason that the map you write doesn't work is that the generator loop is still being mapped to a loop that is being wound around exactly once (in the same direction). (To see the last part more explicitly, try writing the loop; it is $t \mapsto e^{2\pi it}$ for $t \in [0, 1]$. See what you get by composing the loop with your map.)